# How can I deep copy an arbitrary object in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

I have an arbitrary object tagged as Serializable. It has various mutable child objects representing monetary amounts, collections etc. I want to be able to clone this object so if the user modifies it and then reverts their action, I can just replace the clone with a fresh clone.

That implies I need a deep copy because I don't want the users changes to child objects (e.g. adding / inserting items from the collection) appearing on the original.

The objects don't implement Cloneable and as they're autogenerated I can't add such a method either.

Short of painfully handwriting a deep clone is there anyway to accomplish the same in GWT? If this were Java I could consider serializing the object to a byte array stream and deserializing a fresh copy.

I can't do that in GWT. Potentially I could harness RPC because the object is sent to a servlet later. I just don't know if that is easy to do.

Anyone know a simple way I can do a deep copy?

Comment: What generates the types that you want to want to clone?

Comment: A domain specific language. It's not something that can be changed easily and even if it could I don't relish the 500+ objects it generates all having extra GWT bloat to handle deep copy. For the moment I've hand coded deep copy where I need it but even that one instance takes up about 100 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a chance to add an interface or annotation to your domain classes, you can use [gwt-ent](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-ent/) for reflection, and you can easily write your own deep copy semantic by means of reflection. I have used this technique to improve gwt serialization performance in dev mode.

As another solution, you can use gwt default serialization mechanism for deep copy, but unfotunately I dont have any clue how you could accomplish this goal..

Comment: It looks like an interesting project but I don't think I can use it for this. In the end I just handwrote the deepcopy code much though I hated to do it.

Comment: This isn't how I solved it (just wrote the code in the end), but the link is worth knowing.

Comment: @locka any updates on something that is available right now? I'm thinking that I'll have to do something just like this.

Comment: I just wrote a hand crafted solution. I didn't pursue the issue any further.